# how build OpenVPN + Stunnel warped android app

Tags: android, android-studio, openvpn, stunnel, ics-openvpn

as you know for use openvpn + stunnel we need 2 apps ( openvpn ics + ssldroid for Ex )

like this link :

https://www.perfect-privacy.com/en/manuals/android_openvpn_stealth_ssldroid

i should exclude stunnel on app source ? if yes how can i exclude it without exclude all my app traffic ?

im just using
https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn
source